# Docker Run: Mounted Volume not showing change in files

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I am struggling with running the latest changes. Below are the details.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.3

RUN mkdir -p /usr/apps

COPY test.py /usr/apps

RUN pip install mindsdb
CMD [ "python","test.py" ]
```

**Build**

```
docker build -t py37:custom .
```

**Run**

```
docker run -it -v /Development/PetProjects/mindsdb:/usr/apps/  py37:custom
```

But it shows only the changes at the time of build.

Comment: What is the content of */Development/PetProjects/mindsdb*?

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all while starting your container you are not using volumes but `bind mounts`. So you mount directory `/Development/PetProjects/mindsdb` on your host machine to `/usr/apps/` directory. Every change made to files on your host machine in this directory, will be visible in the container, and the other way round.

If you wanted to use volumes, you could create one using `docker volume create` command and then running container with this volume : `docker container run -v volume_name:path_in_container image_name`. Then you would be able to stop container and run it again by passing this volume to run command and changes to `path_in_container` directory could be stored across container creations.

Another thing is that you are trying to mount `/usr/apps/` in your container and you copied a python script there using Dockerfile. Note that in you current `docker run` command contents of `/Development/PetProjects/mindsdb` **will replace content of** `/usr/apps/` in your container and if you do not have your script in `/Development/PetProjects/mindsdb` - script will not be visible in the container.

Moreover your `CMD` seems not to work because of path relativeness. You should change your CMD to `CMD [ "python","/usr/apps/test.py" ]` or use `WORKDIR` option - `WORKDIR /usr/apps/` so your python command could be executed from this directory and script could be visible there.

More information about differences between volumes and bind mounts can be found in [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. IDeally I was looking for a custom image for Python 3.7 which could preserve installed libs, when I run, I then use `docker exec` to SSH and do my work. I am not being able to achieve this. WhY can't I run an image which just give me bash with all libs installed?

Comment: In your case you can create image like you did with all python dependencies. However the container will run as long as the process inside the container is running. You can lanuch your container mounting your directory with project files on host to some directory in container. Then while using `docker run` command you mount your directories and override command to run in container : `docker run -v /host_dir:container_dir image bash`. And now you can work in your container console with files from your your host os.